# How to create div element in Blazor

Tags: c#, html, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm writing an application using Blazor server side and .Net 5. I want when I write text in the search box it will show results in new divs. However, the search results are not displayed. When I debug the code from service works fine.

```html
@page "/"
@using MovieSearch.Service
@using MovieSearch.Data
@using MovieSearch.Helpness
@inject IOMDbService service

<div class="movie-search">
    <div class="search-container">
        <form action="/">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Find a movie" @bind-value="@searchTerm" />
            <button type="submit" @onclick="FindMovies"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="movies">
    @if(moviesResult != null)
    {
        if(!moviesResult.Success)
        {
            foreach(var error in moviesResult.Errors)
            {
                <p>@error.Message</p>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach(var movie in moviesResult.Value)
            {
                <div class="movie">
                    <p>@movie.Title</p>
                    <img src="@movie.Poster" />
                </div>
            }
        }
    }
</div>

@code
{
    private string searchTerm;
    private Result<IEnumerable<Movie>> moviesResult;

    async Task FindMovies()
    {
        moviesResult = await service.FindMovies(searchTerm);
    }
}
```

What can I do to view the results?

Comment: When you say  "When I debug the code from service works fine." it displays data? or the service is returning data?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this part of your code from

```
 <form action="/">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Find a movie" @bind-value="@searchTerm" />
        <button type="submit" @onclick="FindMovies"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
```

to just this

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Find a movie" @bind-value="@searchTerm" />
<button @onclick="FindMovies"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
```

So in other words, remove the form tags, as well as removing the type on the button. I believe that blazor is now actually trying to post the form to whatever action you specified in the form as opposed to the onclick handler you assigned to your button.